# Using the Parse.com Javascript API with users authenticated via the PHP API

Tags: javascript, php, parse-platform

If my site uses the Parse.com PHP API to authenticate users, can I use the Javascript API for ajax requests in such a way that the user, having been logged in via PHP, can access data via the Javascript API?

What would I need to set up differently?

---

#### Some background

I have a site that uses the Parse.com PHP API to handle all backend tasks like storing and retrieving data and authenticating users.

I have several pages that use ajax to refresh page content.

I have written my own Javascript class for sending JSON data to my server via ajax where the info is processed and my PHP code steps in to create, update, or delete Parse objects as needed.

This all works very well with the exception of dealing with files. I see several approaches to dealing with files but I feel like I'm re-inventing the wheel.

The Parse.com Javascript API is great, I'm pretty familiar with it and it already deals with files really well. It would be awesome If I could use it for the ajax.

---

#### I have tried...

Logging in with the PHP API and then attempting to use the Javascript SDK directly to get the current user like

```
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    if (currentUser) {
        // do stuff with the user
        alert(currentUser);
    } else {
        // show the signup or login page
        alert('that didnt work');
    }
```

This did not work.

Comment: test it out ... logon in php .. call 'getCurrentUser()' in php and then make same call over in JS... should be straightforward check

Comment: @RobertRowntree I have added the results of my tests above. Neither method I could think of works, any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can do this by passing the Parse PHP session token to the Javascript API like this:

```
   <?php
        $sessionToken = ParseUser::getCurrentUser()->getSessionToken();
        echo 'var token="'.$sessionToken.'";';
    ?>


    Parse.User.become(token).then(function (user) {
        // The current user is now set to user.
        alert('User has access to javascript API');
    }, function (error) {
        // The token could not be validated.
        alert('Error: ' + error.code + ' ' + error.message);
    });
```